# Can I construct a logic AND on a "power" line

Tags: transistors, mosfet, power-electronics, logic-gates

I have two 12W LED bulbs which are wired in parallel. I control them both with a MOSFET (M1.) Now I want to be able to dim one of the bulbs, but it should still only light up when the "original" MOSFET M1 is on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCDi6T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Would it be possible to construct such an AND gate on a power line? I mean I'm not sure if this can be considered a power line but 1A is definitely not logic current.

Comment: don't see why not

Comment: Make sure your MOSFET in the M2 position can handle 12 V gate-to-source (most can) and you should be fine. The IRFZ44 definitely can, but I'm assuming that's not the actual FET you're using as it isn't suitable for switching with logic levels and wouldn't work well in this circuit (unless the PWM and on/off signals are 10 V instead of typical 5 V, anyway).

Comment: [Here's your circuit in Falstad's circuit simulator](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEAmA7NVbnIBwBYFkBmMIogThxD0hCQVoQFMBaMMAKACURUA2KskhVMtIVVq0a4ZFDkwEHMDgh9hKBHxBqqecltpE4dGVGh4zeJSpDlcGrXapF8co41MwLXjgDMQODhSxk7UxkSyYND0frxCdPy8AglaEeDRdBwATgFBYbQqWjSSKJDZcYyJfJopckIcAO629nhgji36UI3a6npa-LqdZU0D1J2jmpLdo33NgwYcAOZJVAh2K9qY8twBbfm8rsV1KNLIGWdIktE7k7WEq4kl0pfy1wDOdGq11VoIj+AgXwAQwANm8mOUft8alDaGB4GVllDkTCtlMRslkDD1FiFhjBDVQriuviHBtxF0gA). If you turn the power switch on, you can watch the bulb on the left light brightly and the one on the right light dimly.

Comment: I thought I might have problems switching M2 as its source will be connected to M1 drain. No matter how many resources I consume on the matter transistors remain 50% black magic to me..

Comment: @php_nub_qq When M1 is turned on, its drain is close to ground. When M1 is turned off, you don't care what M2 does, so it doesn't matter that you can't turn M2 on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine.

- M1 on, M2 source is GND, M2 switches on with PWM
- M1 off, M2 source is pulled to 12V via LAMP1, so M1 can never turn on

Just be mindful of the max Vgs your FETs can allow. M2 can have as much as -12V Vgs when M1 is off. The IRLZ44N FET shown has a max Vgs of +/-16V so it’s ok; another FET might not be (many are +/-10V.) This limit will be found in “Absolute Maximum Ratings” in the datasheet.

Comment: If M1 is off, doesn't that leave M2's source floating, thus "infinite" resistance on the (M2) G-S path? Ideally there should be a pull down on the gate, I don't understand how can negative voltage end up there?

Comment: When M1 is off, M2 source is pulled up by the lamp, that is, to +12V. So M2 Vgs is  below threshold and therefore M2 is ‘off’; Vgs will be either (0V - 12V) or (5V - 12V) depending on the state of the PWM signal.

Comment: Oh you mean it's being pulled to 12V by LAMP1, I see now, I was ignoring it completely and was so confused how could LAMP2 cause 12V on M2's source, huh.